# SQL Server creating a view and joining tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of tables as follows:

Book, columns: Bookcode, title, PublisherCode, Type, Paperback (y/n)

Author, columns: AuthorNum, AuthorLast, AuthorFirst (names)

Publisher, columns: PublisherCode, PublisherName, City (I don't believe I need this right now)

Wrote: columns: Bookcode, AuthorNum, Sequence

I need to create a view called "FictionBestSellers" that shows Book title, Author First Name, Author Last Name, Paperback and Book Type

This is what I have:

```
CREATE VIEW FictionBestSellers as Book, AuthorFname, AutheorLname, Paperback, btype 
select book.Title, Author.AuthorFirst, Author.AuthorLast, book.Paperback, book.type 
from Book, Author, Wrote
book join Wrote   
on book.BookCode =  wrote.BookCode
where book.type = 'MYS' or book.type = 'SFI' or book.type = 'HOR'
```

Right now it is telling me 
    "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FictionBestSellers, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Book'."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW FictionBestSellers(Book, AuthorFname, AutheorLname, Paperback, btype)
AS 
select book.Title, Author.AuthorFirst, Author.AuthorLast, book.Paperback, book.type 
from Book
  join wrote
    on book.BookCode =  wrote.BookCode
  join Author
    on wrote.AuthorNum= AuthorNum
where book.type = 'MYS' or book.type = 'SFI' or book.type = 'HOR'
```

Comment: +1 for this syntax View_Name(Column_Names...) didnt know it was a possible :)

Comment: @M.Ali It is optional but it is possible. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Comment: Thanks but the link you have provided is in Russian I think, I dont speak Russian :)

Comment: Both answers worked, this one was just missing Author.Authornum on the line "on wrote.AuthorNum= Author.AuthorNum"

Answer (score 2):

This is the right SQL.

```
CREATE VIEW FictionBestSellers 
AS 
SELECT b.Title AS Book
, a.AuthorFirst AS AuthorFname
, a.AuthorLast AS AutheorLname
, b.Paperback AS Paperback
, b.type AS BType
FROM Wrote w         
    INNER JOIN Book b ON w.Bookcode = b.Bookcode
    INNER JOIN Author a on w.AuthorNum = a.AuthorNum
WHERE b.type IN ('MYS', 'SFI', 'HOR')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW FictionBestSellers 
as 
select book.Title         AS Book
     , Author.AuthorFirst AS AuthorFname
     , Author.AuthorLast  AS AutheorLname
     , book.Paperback     AS Paperback
     , book.type          AS btype
from Book INNER JOIN Wrote
ON   Book.Bookcode = Wrote.Bookcode
INNER JOIN Author
ON   Wrote.AuthorNum = Author.AuthorNum
where book.type = 'MYS' 
OR    book.type = 'SFI' 
OR    book.type = 'HOR'
```